# How to take value from cell in Google sheets, to be used as number variable in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to use the value of Cell A3 as a variable to specify the exact size of a particular array. Code below isn't working, why?

A3 is a =COUNTA(B2:VF2)-1 which currently evaluates to 446

```
function RangeCopyToLog() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Xp Log");
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
  var copyColEnd = destSheet.getRange('A3') + 1 //Problem is here
  destSheet.insertRows(lastRow + 1,1);
  destSheet.getRange(1,3,1,copyColEnd).copyTo(destSheet.getRange(34,3,1,copyColEnd), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
 // destSheet.getRange('D1:D30').copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
 // destSheet.getRange('D1:D30').clearContent();
};
```

Error presented is: "Cannot convert Range1 to (class)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.getRange() only returns the range, not the value. Change this line

```
var copyColEnd = destSheet.getRange('A3') + 1
```

to

```
var copyColEnd = destSheet.getRange('A3').getValue() + 1
```